# How to convert a text file into swi-prolog facts?

Tags: parsing, prolog, swi-prolog, file-conversion

I want prolog to read a text file uploaded by the user, convert it into prolog facts and store it in the Knowledge Base.This text file is supposed to be a student transcript in the following format. I am fairly new to prolog, so, I don't know if it's even possible as the text file has some junk and repetitive data and I want to take only certain parts of it.

**Example: This is the text file**

```
Main Menu </cgi/regweb/stu_login.main_menu>

_

    *Academic Transcript*_

    *Year/Semester:*

        2013 / 1    *Number :*  20131234
    *Name               :*  Mary Georgia    *Advisor :*     Mr.Paul Watson
    *Degree             :*  B.Sc. in Information Systems    *Status    :*   

    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    *Course*    *Course Name*   *Credit*    *Grade*     *Status*    *Repeated*
    ENGL    154     LANGUAGE DEVELOPMENT I  3   A   -   0
    ITCS    103     COMPUTER PROGRAMMING 1  4   A   -   0
    ITIS    101     PERSONAL PRODUCTIVITY WITH IS TECHNOLOGY    3   A-  -   0
    MATHS   101     CALCULUS I  3   B+  -   0

    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    *Semester Credits Attended   :*     13  *Passed:*   13  *GPA:*  3.92
    *Cumulative Credits Attended:*  13  *Passed:*   13  *GPA:*  3.92

    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */STUDENT COPY - äÓÎÉ ÇáØÇáÈ /*

    *åÐå ÇáäÓÎÉ ÛíÑ ÑÓãíÉ æáÇ ÊÚÑÖ ÍÇáÉ ÇáØÇáÈ ÇáÃßÇÏíãíÉ
    Úáì ÇáØÇáÈ ÇÓÊÎÑÇÌ äÓÎÉ ßÔÝ ÇáÏÑÌÇÊ ÇáÑÓãíÉ ãä ãßÊÈ ÇáÊÓÌíá*
    *This is not an Official Transcript and Does Not State The Academic Status
    Students must obtain detailed Official Transcript of their Academic
    Status from the Registration Offices *

    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    *****************  End  Of   Transcript  For   2013 / 1  *******************

    ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    *Year/Semester:*

        2013 / 2    *Number :*  20131234
    *Name               :*  Mary Georgia    *Advisor :*     Mr.Paul Watson
    *Degree             :*  B.Sc. in Information Systems    *Status    :*   


    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    *Course*    *Course Name*   *Credit*    *Grade*     *Status*    *Repeated*
    ACC     112     FINANCIAL ACCOUNTING I  3   B-  -   0
    ECON    140     MICROECONOMICS  3   A-  -   0
    ENGL    155     LANGUAGE DEVELOPMENT II     3   A   -   0
    ITCS    104     COMPUTER PROGRAMMING 2  4   A   -   0
    MGT     131     INTRO. TO BUSINESS ADMINISTRATION   3   A   -   0

    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    *Semester Credits Attended   :*     16  *Passed:*   16  *GPA:*  3.82
    *Cumulative Credits Attended:*  29  *Passed:*   29  *GPA:*  3.87

    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */STUDENT COPY - äÓÎÉ ÇáØÇáÈ /*

    *åÐå ÇáäÓÎÉ ÛíÑ ÑÓãíÉ æáÇ ÊÚÑÖ ÍÇáÉ ÇáØÇáÈ ÇáÃßÇÏíãíÉ
    Úáì ÇáØÇáÈ ÇÓÊÎÑÇÌ äÓÎÉ ßÔÝ ÇáÏÑÌÇÊ ÇáÑÓãíÉ ãä ãßÊÈ ÇáÊÓÌíá*
    *This is not an Official Transcript and Does Not State The Academic Status
    Students must obtain detailed Official Transcript of their Academic
    Status from the Registration Offices *

    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    *****************  End  Of   Transcript  For   2013 / 2  *******************

    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Prolog Knowledge Base:**

> *student(Number, Name, Total_Credits_Passed,Cumulative GPA,Adviser)*

```
student(20131234,'Mary Georgia',29,3.87,'Mr.Paul Watson').
```

> *coursestaken(Number,Year,Semester,courseslist(course1,course2,course3,course4,course5,course6,course7),grades(gradeofcourse1,gradeofcourse2,gradeofcourse3,gradeofcourse4,gradeofcourse5,gradeofcourse6,gradeofcourse7)*

```
coursestaken(20131234,2013,1,courseslist(ENGL154,ITCS103,ITIS101,MATHS101,_,_,_),grades(A,A,A-,B+,_,_,_)).
```

do same for the rest of the semesters if there are any.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Start with a smaller example! Much too complex for a novice.

Comment: Of course it's possible. It will just be a bit of work. :) Have you looked at the I/O predicates in the SWI Prolog documentation?

Comment: @false Actually, it's a part of my course project, AI Academic Adviser. Now, I have the option to go for much simpler way, i-e, to limit the scope by assuming that the student is a 4th year student and suggest him/her only 4th level courses based on their CGPA. However, to me, storing students' and the courses taken info directly from their transcripts seems more practical and better way of doing it. So, I am gonna give it a try nonetheless,and if it didn't work out then I'll go with the simpler option.

Comment: @lurker Well, that's what I am confused about. I've come across some libraries like sgml that parses html,xml ,.. files and then there's another one called DCG, that I believe parses simple phrases or sentences. I don't think any of these would work in my case.So, will I be able to do it using I/O predicates or are there any other libraries that could work?

Comment: Your file is just a text file with no special format like HTML, XML, etc. So you don't want a special library. You'll need to use the [standard file I/O library](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=IO) and do some of the parsing yourself. That's what I meant by *It will just be a bit of work*. :)

Comment: Alright! thanks for the info:)